# ¿A qué se debe y cómo podría solucionar este error de php?

Tags: php, composer

**UPDATE, CÓDIGO DE COMPOSER.JSON**

```
{
"name": "jaybizzle/crawler-detect",
"type": "library",
"description": "CrawlerDetect is a PHP class for detecting bots/crawlers/spiders via the user agent",
"keywords": ["crawler", "crawler detect", "crawler detector", "crawlerdetect", "php crawler detect"],
"homepage": "https://github.com/JayBizzle/Crawler-Detect/",
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Mark Beech",
        "email": "m@rkbee.ch",
        "role": "Developer"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8|^5.5|^6.5|^9.4"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Jaybizzle\\CrawlerDetect\\": "src/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "test": "vendor/bin/phpunit"
}
}
```

estoy intentando importar un archivo de GitHub que requiere de composer. He realizado los siguientes pasos:

1. Instalación de dependencias a través del cmd con el siguiente comando " `composer require jaybizzle/crawler-detect`"
2. Importación de la carpeta descargada `Jaybizzle` en el directorio donde tengo los archivos descargados.
3. Inclusión del código tal y como lo dice la siguiente URL:https://github.com/JayBizzle/Crawler-Detect

Al importar me da el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Jaybizzle\CrawlerDetect\CrawlerDetect" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\tusc\trie\tt\index.php:121 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tusc\trie\tt\index.php on line 121

Código que he hecho:

```
<?php
use Jaybizzle\CrawlerDetect\CrawlerDetect;

$CrawlerDetect = new CrawlerDetect;

// Check the user agent of the current 'visitor'
if($CrawlerDetect->isCrawler()) {
    
$tesr  = '<script type="text/javascript">

console.log("btttier");
 setInterval("window.stop()", 100);

</script>';
echo $tesr;

echo $CrawlerDetect->getMatches();
}


?>
```

Comment: que pone en la linea 121 del index.php ?  asi de primeras, parece que no has cargado el Autoload que hay en vendor (quizas no tengas el `require('vendor/autoload.php` ?). Puedes poner el contenido de tu composer.json?

Comment: @Jakala en la línea 121 pone:
`$CrawlerDetect = new CrawlerDetect;`
y si jeje, no tengo el `require('vendor/autoload.php')` pero no me aparece en el directorio como tal. Ahora mismo subo en la pregunta el contenido del .json

Comment: el composer.json que has añadido es el de la libreria. Como tal ese no tienes que tenerlo en el directorio raiz de tu proyecto. Si haces el `composer require...`tiene que haberte creado un composer.json propio, y un directorio vendor con el archivo autoload.php. Por otra parte tu codigo debe tener el `require`para que el autoload pueda cargar los namespaces, y asi poder localizar la clase (en este caso, CrawlerDetect)